# float and auto height

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a couple of classes there so let me post them first.

***HTML:***

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="area">

    </div>
</div><!-- content closed -->
```

***CSS:***

```
.content {
    background-color: #eee;
    height: auto;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #555;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    float: right;
}

.area {
    background-color: #777;
    width: 590px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

So, you can basically see that every single class have height set on "auto". Thats good cause I want content to follow sidebar and area. And they will have plenty of content inside of them.

Now...
.sidebar is set on float:right; so it doesnt really affect to move the content that stands below. Which is footer in my case.

I am wondering how to make the object thats floating, to move the parts that are below of it, depending on auto set height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you are trying to position footer underneath your content that is floated right, you need to clear the float:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">

    </div>

    <div class="area">

    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    This is the footer
</div><!-- content closed -->
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xmw7M/1/

Comment: Yeh was playing more arround till I was awaiting for answer. Although I've typed into css of footer clear:both; I believe its same effect and it worked. Thanks for posting the answer steve. I'll check it as correct answer in 5 minutes.